# how to make fast backgroundImages in expo react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How can I make a fast `backgroundImage` in react native? I am using expo, I have already make a background image, but have a fadeout and a fadein. This bother me, I want something fast, like just appear the image without this lag, how can I do this?

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Modal, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { Image } from 'expo-image'

const images = [
    require("../../assets/imgs/carrousel/1.jpg"),
    require("../../assets/imgs/carrousel/2.jpg"),
    require("../../assets/imgs/carrousel/3.png"),
    require("../../assets/imgs/carrousel/4.png"),
    ...
];

const Conectar = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const navigation = useNavigation()


    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % images.length);
        }, 3000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground source={images[index]} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
            ...
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
    );
};


export default Conectar;
```

Comment: I see you are using `require` but can't you just add the image as a string in  your template e.g. 

`const images = [
    "../../assets/imgs/carrousel/1.jpg",
    ...
];`

then in your code do something like this:

`<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">`

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp